# Meaning of 'at fittest' and 'at finest'

Tags: adjectives

> But even Anderson [ at his fittest and finest ] would have struggled against the Serb in this mood, on that stage.

[(source)](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/comeback-man/article24445851.ece)

What is the meaning of at fittest and finest in this context?

Comment: Note that it is "at **his** fittest" and "at **his** finest".  Just saying "at fittest/finest" would be incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have already looking up "fit" and "fine" in the dictionary, and didn't find any relevant definition.

"Fittest", in a sports context, refers to "physical fitness", which is the athlete's physical ability to play the sport at their highest level.

> The two boxers started out strong in the first round, but by the fifth Collins' lack of **fitness** began to take its toll, and by the seventh he was simply too exhausted to continue the fight.

"Finest", in this context, refers to the athlete's *quality* of play, and more or less simply means "best".

> Collins was in his **finest** form that day, simply out-boxing his opponent, and was certainly ahead on the judges' scorecards before the final round.

In your article the writer is saying that even if Anderson had been *the most physically fit* he'd been in his career, and *played the best game* of his career, he still would have had trouble beating "the Serb" (Novak Djokovic).